# Change url of one site to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two websites. There is a link in website1 that goes to a page in website2. I don't want my users to know that they are in website2, or get redirected to website2. Is there anyway to do this?

I thought I could do it with url rewriting but I couldn't.

Comment: I am not sure on this but may be `Server.Transfer` is what you are looking for.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` is an option, however it is unreliable.

Comment: Server.Transfer only works if you're on the same server. Is that the case?

Comment: I have both websites in a same server, but they are in different places. I know I can't use Transfer if  it's not a virtual path, I tried to give it the actual address, and it didn't work.

Comment: Applications Request Routing module of IIS could be solution.

Comment: Website1 has more view, but I want to website2 has more view, so when someone try to search, find website2 on the top. If I use iframe is it gonna give website2 any point for example in google search? Because that's the whole idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the site you want to include (site 2) contains links, forms and other dynamic content. In that case, I think the only option is to use an `<iframe>` in site 1 in which site 2 is displayed. The URL of site 1 will not change, and the user has the impression that site 2 is site 1 - unless it has a fundamentally different layout, of course.

Note that using `<iframe>` is considered bad practice in most cases, but for your requirements it may be a valid solution and it's [still supported/improved](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/html5-iframe-attributes.htm) in HTML 5.

Note that site 2 will still be visible in google, and if clicked it will be shown without site 1; unless you add some scripting in site 2 to redirect to site 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
Server.Transfer("/Myasps/ASP2.asp")
```

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

A very good comparison is provided [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/775221/Server-Transfer-VS-Response-Redirect-Simplified)

> Use “Server.Transfer” when you want to navigate pages which reside on the same server, use “Response.Redirect” when you want to navigate between pages which resides on different server and domain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered implementing a proxy? Basically you take the user request and forward on your server side to the 2nd server. If you have resources coming from that location they will come with the 2nd site url but that's not visible to the user.

If your calls are only data calls then everything will go through proxy, no one will known about the 2nd site existence.